# Check for the presence of a key/value pair in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the shortest way to check for the existence of a certain key/value pair in a dictionary if I don't know that the key exists?

So far, I've come up with:

```
if 'key' in my_dict and my_dict['key'] == 'value':
    do_something()
```

This is really long with longer variable names or longer key/value names, such as:

```
if 'X-Powered-By' in self.request.headers and self.request.headers['X-Powered-By'] == 'NodeBB':
    do_something()
```

What's a shorter way to check for the presence of a key and a corresponding value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fetch the value, and compare it right away:

```
# default return value is None if key is not found
if mydict.get("key") == "somevalue"
```

or

```
# Or specify your own default value
if mydict.get("key", False) == "somevalue"
```

Check out [Python dict.get docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: Thanks, you were the first response and this is shorter than Apero's response. I'll accept this if I can.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, none of the answers captures the full problem. If the value that is being queried for happens to be `None` or whatever default value one provides, the `get()`-based solutions fail. The following might be the most generally applicable solution, not relying on defaults, truly checking the existence of a key (unlike `get()`), and not over-'except'-ing `KeyError`s (unlike the other `try-except` answer) while still using `O(1)` `dict` lookup (unlike `items()` approach):

```
try:
    assert my_dict[key] == value:
except (KeyError, AssertionError):
    do_sth_else()  # or: pass
else:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for existence of the key

```
if not 'key' in my_dict:
    my_dict['key'] = 'some default value'
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, my suggestion, to make your code more readable:

```
headers = self.request.headers
if headers.get('X-Powered-By') == 'NodeBB':
    do_something()
```

This could be another short code **but definitely not efficient** as a `dict.get`:

```
if ('X-Powered-By', 'NodeBB') in self.request.headers.items():
    do_something()
```

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of that myself :)

Comment: This works. However, it disregards the true power of a `dict`. The other solutions are `O(1)`, this is `O(N)`!

Comment: @Apero I've upvoted your answer, as the question was about conciseness, not speed. I'm never going to be dealing with large `dict`s, so speed is not critical. I appreciate your answer. (this is also something I thought of myself, I was looking to see if there were alternate solutions). I'll still accept Davor Lucic's solution since it's shorter, but I don't have a problem with the slower speed of your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't agree with those. Not all code has to be the fastest possible, especially in my case where it's for a personal project rather than commercial software.

Comment: but Davor's answer is neat, I would just recommend you to use the short variable name as I suggested on top of my answer, and then it's easier to read